# Django annotate relation with specific object

Tags: python, django

I have two models in my Django database:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    signed_up_to=models.ManyToManyField(Piece)
class Piece(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
```

When I pull Piece objects from my database, I would like to annotate (Bool or Integer) whether or not the Piece appears in *signed_up_to* of a **specific** Member. I've looked around for an answer all over the internet, but with no success. Hope there's anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `Member` object is *`member`*, you can make use of an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Piece.objects.annotate(
    has_member=Exists(
        Member.signed_up_to.through.objects.filter(
            piece_id=OuterRef('pk'),
            member_id=member.pk
        )
    )
)
```

So `has_member` will be `True` if *`member`* has this `Piece` object in its `signed_up_to` relation, and `False` otherwise.

Comment: Perfect! Dankjewel Willem!

Comment: Oh, for Christ's sake. Man, I admire you so bad. This is perfect... Could you please share with me what's the need of using `OuterRef`? I just don't get it, because the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#referencing-columns-from-the-outer-queryset) say that you should use it if you're going to refer a field from the subquery, but in your example (and in the [example used](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) in the docs) I don't see that usage. @Willem

Comment: @revliscano: it means we take the `pk` (so the `id` field) of the outer query of this subquery, so the `id` of the `Piece` object.

Comment: @revliscano Exists is a subclass of Subquery.